# How to join two tables with same column names but with different data using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

Supposing

df1,

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
A    |  131 | 666  | 777  |
B    |  123 | 345  | 435  |
C    | 1424 | 3214 | 2314 |
```

df2,

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
A    |  10  | 1    | 0    |
B    |  20  | 14   | 68   |
C    |  23  | 43   | 4    |
```

final df that I want to achieve,

```
col1 | col2           | col3         | col4      |
A    |  131 (10%)     | 666 (1%)     | 777       |
B    |  123 (20%)     | 345 (14%)    | 435 (68%) |
C    |  1424 (23%)    | 3214 (43%)   | 2314 (4%) |
```

P.S. The numbers are just random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or `applymap`:

```
>>> (df1.set_index('col1').astype(str).add(df2.set_index('col1')
                      .applymap(lambda x: f' ({x}%)' if x else ''))
                      .reset_index())
  col1        col2        col3       col4
0    A   131 (10%)    666 (1%)        777
1    B   123 (20%)   345 (14%)  435 (68%)
2    C  1424 (23%)  3214 (43%)  2314 (4%)
>>>
```

This code adds the strings from `df2` with a percentage sign if it isn't `0`. It uses `set_index` to merge on the same `col1`, and uses `applymap` to format it.

Comment: This does not produce expected output: OP wants `777` but your code produces `0 (777%)`

Comment: Sorry my bad, I had his df's reversed, I was using OP's df1 as df2

Comment: @MuhammadHassan yeap

Answer (score 3):

You can convert DataFrames to strings, replace `0` to missing values, add `( %)`, so not added for missing values and last is added first `DataFrame`:

```
df = ((df1.set_index('col1').astype(str) + 
      (' (' + df2.set_index('col1').astype(str).replace('0', np.nan) + '%)').fillna(''))
      .reset_index())
print (df)
  col1        col2        col3       col4
0    A   131 (10%)    666 (1%)        777
1    B   123 (20%)   345 (14%)  435 (68%)
2    C  1424 (23%)  3214 (43%)  2314 (4%)
```

Another idea is test values by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df11 = df1.set_index('col1').astype(str)
df22 = df2.set_index('col1').astype(str)

df = (df11 + (' (' + df22 + '%)').mask(df22.eq('0'), '')).reset_index()
      
print (df)
  col1        col2        col3       col4
0    A   131 (10%)    666 (1%)        777
1    B   123 (20%)   345 (14%)  435 (68%)
2    C  1424 (23%)  3214 (43%)  2314 (4%)
```